# saving dictionary to database from template flask

Tags: python, dictionary, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

i have an html template that is looping through a list of dictionaries and serving out the values for the keys:

```
{% for x in data[0:5] %}
    <td id='{{data[x]}}'>
        <p> {{ x['score'] }} </p>
        <a href="{{x['url']}}"> {{ x['title'] }} </a>
        <br>
        <a href='#' id='save_post'><button> Add To Favorites </button></a>
    </td>
{% endfor %}
```

The  tag at the bottom of this piece of html is calling an ajax request to save this particular dictionary to the database. So, basically if the button is pressed, it will save that index (which is the dictionary) to the database.

I've tried a few different things, but what I have now is:

```
@app.route('/add_to_favorites', methods=['POST'])
def add_to_favorites(post):
    data = get_info()
    post = data[x]
    fav= Favorite(title=post.get('title'), url=post.get('url'), score=post.get('score'), user_id=current_user.id)
    db.session.add(fav)
    db.session.commit()
```

Yet i get a 500 response and the post is not saved.

How can i make my dictionary an object so that I can save the object to the database using a button on the template? What am i doing wrong here?

AJAX request:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type=text/javascript>
    $(function() {
        $('a#add_to_favorites').bind('click', function() {
          $.ajax({
              type : 'POST',
              url : '/add_to_favorites'
          });
          console.log('working');
        });
    });
  </script>
```

Comment: Could you show us the actual ajax request as well.

Comment: @Vallentin i posted it in the original post as it was not formatting correctly. 

The console does return the string "working".